# Laravel mass update with different value based on condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table structure like:

```
id    //primary_key
value
changed_value    //on update value column should not be updated instead changed value should be updated
status    // 0 - default, 1- updated
am_id  //foreign_key
```

Now, to mass update I am doing as follows:

```
Model::where('am_id',$request->am_id)
        ->where('value',$request->value)
        ->update([
                         'changed_value' => '$request->value',
                         'status' => 1
                ]);
```

However, we should not set status as 1 blindly, as there is one condition. It's if  the value of `value` column is equal to the `$request->value` the status should be `0` instead.

## How this scenario could appear?

Initially, after inserting the first row looks like

```
+-----+-------+---------------+--------+-------+
| id  | value | changed_value | status | am_id |
+-----+-------+---------------+--------+-------+
|  1  | 20    | null          | 0      | 1     |  
+-----+-------+---------------+--------+-------+
```

After 1st update

```
+-----+-------+---------------+--------+-------+
| id  | value | changed_value | status | am_id |
+-----+-------+---------------+--------+-------+
|  1  | 20    | 40            | 1      | 1     |   // changed_value - 40 , status 1
+-----+-------+---------------+--------+-------+
```

After 2nd Update (let's say the value is updated to 20), in this case as the `value === changed_value` the status should be updated as `0` not `1`

```
+-----+-------+---------------+--------+-------+
| id  | value | changed_value | status | am_id |
+-----+-------+---------------+--------+-------+
|  1  | 20    | 20            | 0      | 1     |     // changed_value - 20 , status 0
+-----+-------+---------------+--------+-------+
```

This means, during the model update in below-mentioned code. I want to insert a condition, `if( value == $request->value) status = 0 else status = 1`

```
Model::where('am_id',$request->am_id)
        ->where('value',$request->value)
        ->update([
                     'changed_value' => '$request->value',
                      'status' => 1
                ]);
```

Comment: At first update if  the value === changed_value then what is the status?

Comment: It should be still 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you could always use raw sql if performance was an issue.

```
DB::unprepared(' 
    update model 
    set status = case when (changed_value = "'.$request->value.'") then 0 else 1 end 
    and changed_value = "'.$request->value.'" 
    where value = "'.$request->value.'";
')
```

Edit: You can do it in Eloquent with 2 queries with a subquery to filter the ids of the already updated rows.

```
// get ids of all matching status 1 but don't execute the query
$matches = Model::select('id')->where('am_id',$request->am_id)->where('value',$request->value)
    ->where('changed_value', $request->value);

// change matching status 1
Model::whereIn('id', $matches)
    ->update([
        'changed_value' => '$request->value',
        'status' => 1
    ]);

// matching not in status 1
Model::where('am_id',$request->am_id)
    ->where('value',$request->value)
    ->where('changed_value', '!=', $request->value)
    ->whereNotIn('id', $matches)
    ->update([
        'changed_value' => '$request->value',
        'status' => 0
    ]);
```

Comment: Could you make query builder instead?

Comment: Other than the link @matticustard provided I'm not sure how that would translate to query builder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
$value = Model::where('am_id',$request->am_id)->first()->value;
if($request->value == $value){
    $status = 1;
}else{
    $status = 0;
}
Model::where('am_id',$request->am_id)
    ->update([
         'changed_value' => '$request->value',
         'status' => $status
    ]);
```

Comment: I don't think its the appropriate way as it is considering the first row value and updating the whole row lists.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Eloquent was not designed to handle this kind of mass update (where you want different conditions) with a single query.  You would have to step through the models, or resort to the query builder.

```php
$models = Model::where('am_id',$request->am_id)->get();

$models->map(function ($model) use ($request) {

    // status
    $status = $model->value === $request->value ? 0 : 1;

    // update model
    $model->update([
        'changed_value' => $request->value,
        'status' => $status
    ]);

    return $model;
});
```

EDIT: There are some query builder ideas on this page that might allow you to make something reusable, instead of just writing raw SQL any time you need to do this.
https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/575#issuecomment-300731748

Comment: is there any advantage of using `map` over `foreach` how many query would this map function run?

Comment: could you suggest query buillder for this? I am open to query builder as well.

Comment: It would run a separate query for every model record, unfortunately.  You could use `foreach` if you prefer — I just find this to be more elegant as it results in an updated collection without the extra steps of referencing keys.

Comment: I added a link that might help to give you some ideas regarding the query builder and making a reusable function.